# Unable to add sprite frames and use in CCSprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm loading a texture atlas using the code:

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"zones.plist"];

    CGSize screenSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].viewSize;
    sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"Z_11.png"];
    sprite.position = ccp(screenSize.width * 0.5, screenSize.height * 0.5);
    [self addChild:sprite];
```

but nothing is added.
I also tried:

```
CCSpriteFrame *sf = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"ZONE_2"];
    sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrame:sf];
```

i get the error:

```
'Invalid spriteFrame for sprite'
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: show the contents of zones-hd.plist (if you support hd).

Answer (score 0):

if zones.plist contains definition for a frame, it is probablly `ZONE_2.png`  (assuming it was produced by a tool such as TexturePacker).  Try :

```
CCSpriteFrame *sf = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"ZONE_2.png"];
```

edit :

also make certain you have the appropriate resources (ie zones-hd.plist etc...) for all the devices/display-modes you plan to support.